# How to authenticate to a REST endpoint on Google Cloud Firestore API

Tags: python, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am looking at writing a short python/nodejs script that will call out to the [exportDocuments](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases/exportDocuments) API route from Google's Firestore.

This page shows how to use [gcloud](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import) but it just isn't an option since I am calling from inside an AWS Lambda function.

I am a GCP newbie, but not python/REST newbie.  I couldn't find an SDK that exposes this endpoint (but maybe I am wrong here).

I did poked around the **terrible** documentation for GCP and made a service account and gave it the `Cloud Datastore Import Export Admin` role.

I also looked around at Google's [Application Default Creds](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production) which doesn't help me since I am in Lambda.

The one thing I didn't dive into is the [http.proto](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/api/http.proto) that GCP uses because I am not familiar with it and it looks like a big rabbit hole.

So does anyone have sample python or nodejs code for how make a POST request and provide a service account to a GCP REST [endpoint](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases/exportDocuments)? Or is there an sdk that uses `v1beta1` from firestore.  I wasn't able to find it at [their docs page](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.17.x/v1beta1.FirestoreClient)

Comment: See the the Cloud Firestore REST API  doc here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api